# Archer IRM : How do I reference the sub level of a levelled application using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, archer, datafeed

Here's the standard XSLT, that's included in an Archer supplied data feed. It points to an single level application:

```
<Product_Service>
  <xsl:for-each select="Field[@guid = 'a125b824-7d85-44a3-a1ef-3d7360fef714']/Reference">
      <ID>
        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
      </ID>
   /xsl:for-each>
</Product_Service>
```

However, we have created a second level in the Products application, so there is now a sub level from which I need the values.  I tried swapping the OOTB GUID out for the field GUID in my application's sub level but nothing came back, so I can only assume I must somehow reference the first level too? Worth noting, the cross-reference points directly to the sub level.

Advice welcome. Cheers.

I am expecting the values which reside in the referenced GUID to show in the output but no values are returned.